# Asp.net core mvc -- Changing partial on user log in

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a partial that looks like this:

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log out</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Registrieren" asp-action="Create">Anmelden</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Details">Einloggen</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

Now i'm not using the SignInManager to handle the login. I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session with a cookie.
I would like to handle the condition when the partial is shown by code. Like so:

```
if(session == xx)
            {
                //show logged in part of partial

            }
```

or even maybe something like

```
name = HttpContext.Session.GetString("nameKey");
if(name != "")
{
 //show logged in part of partial
}
```

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: How are you actually signing in? The answer depends on whether you use the built-in framework or not

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm using middleware to set a session. I'm using entity framework and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Basically I wanna say if session exists show logged in partial.

Comment: Then you should be able to use `@if (Session["whatever"] != null)...`

Comment: I'd probably have to give the session a name then. Not sure which one it uses on default. I'll check it now. thanks

Comment: the standard in applications is that you use to have som object about user in ViewBag after logged in so you can take the user data like email name etc. So you can ask is ViewBag.UserInfo != null or something like this

Comment: it can't resolve if (Session["whatever"] != null) session in this even though i added using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session

Comment: I think what you suggested doesn't exist in asp.net core

Comment: At least in asp.net core 1.0, session could be accessed via `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;` + `Context.Session.GetString("key")` within a view. I'm not sure if that has changed in 2.0.

Comment: @Chris yes, that works perfectly. Ah i see now. let me try in razor.

Comment: @Chris! That does work! Thanks a lot! You can post it as an answer if you like for me to accept it.